# Synchronize gitlab password with cas

Tags: gitlab, omniauth, cas, gitlab-omnibus

I've configured Gitlab CE 10.6 with OmniAuth and a CAS server that authenticates against two Active Directories and a users db. The login process is working fine to make the automatic signup, etc... now, i've been asked to synchronize the password from my CAS server with the gitlab password to avoid this extra step for the user, Is there any configuration or property to do this? If not what do you recommend me to do to solve this requirement?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What CAS version? Please be specific.

Comment: Hi, the cas version is 3.5.2, the implementation is Jasig Central Authentication Service. Sorry for the lack of information, i just assumed this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible out of the box, but you can extend the current authentication strategies/handlers to grab the password and do what you need with them. Each handler has a `preAuthenticate()` method that might be useful in this case.

Comment: In what location can i find the handlers?

Comment: At the moment i am just setting the username as a temporal password in /home/git/gitlab/lib/gitlab/auth/o_auth/user.rb

Comment: Look at all children of AuthenticationHandler, probably in the deployerConfigContext.xml file. For this to work, you need to extend the one you're using and write code to sync passwords.